# How to position d3 legends below x axis

Tags: d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.legend line {
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.ages.forEach(function(d) { d.y0 /= y0; d.y1 /= y0; });
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.ages[0].y1 - a.ages[0].y1; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.select(".state:last-child").selectAll(".legend")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x.rangeBand() / 2 + "," + y((d.y0 + d.y1) / 2) + ")"; });

  legend.append("line")
      .attr("x2", 10);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 13)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

});

</script>
```

How can I place the legends below x axis.
And how can I add as rectangles.
Just the way legends are in this link
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208
Can someone plaese explain the tranform translate in detail.

Comment: Which part of the transform don't you understand?

Comment: .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x.rangeBand() / 2 + "," + y((d.y0 + d.y1) / 2) + ")"; });

Comment: That code doesn't appear anywhere in the example you've linked to. You're not asking us to explain your own code to you, are you?